# deleting numbers from a stack?

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, stack

```
class stack_class
{
private:

    struct stack_struct *head;

public:
    stack_class();
    ~stack_class();
    void pushNumber(int number);
    void popNumber();
    void findNumber();
    void clearStack();
    void sizeFinder();
    void printStack();

};

void stack_class::popNumber()
{
    stack_struct *pointerPop=NULL,*pointerPop2=NULL;
    int popCounter=0,i=0;
    pointerPop2=tailPointer;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"\nNo Member to Delete.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        while(pointerPop2)
        {
            popCounter++;
            //cout<<pointerFunc3->number<<endl;
            pointerPop2=pointerPop2->next_number;
        }
        pointerPop=tailPointer;
        while(i<(popCounter-2))
        {
            pointerPop=pointerPop->next_number;
            i++;
        }
        pointerPop->next_number=NULL;
        delete head;
        head=pointerPop;
    }

}

void stack_class::printStack()
{
    pointerFunc3=tailPointer;
    if(tailPointer==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"\nNo Members in List.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"\n\nList Is:\n";
        while(pointerFunc3)
        {
            cout<<pointerFunc3->number<<endl;
            pointerFunc3=pointerFunc3->next_number;
        }
    }

}
```

constructor to class

```
stack_class::stack_class()
{
    head=NULL;
}
```

This is my code, the problem with it is, when I POP the very last number and try to print the list, it enters an infinite loop and prints garbage. when I press the delete option after everything in the list has been deleted, the program freezes. Any suggestions why this is acting like this??And how do I fix it?

Comment: @Chad you should only flag as duplicate if the duplicate question have answers.

Answer (score 1):

Stack is meant to follow last in first out policy. You can delete/pop the last number you have pushed to the stack. For doing that your pop must be something like this:

```
int stack_class::popNumber(){
stack_struct *pointerPop=NULL; //,*pointerPop2=NULL; //not needed
int number; //number poped
//int popCounter=0,i=0;
//pointerPop2=tailPointer;
if(head==NULL)
{
    std::cout<<"\nNo Member to POP.\n";
}
else
{
    pointerPop = head;
    number = head->number;
    delete head;
    head = pointerPop;
    return number;//control ended

    //[[this part is not neccessary
    while(pointerPop2)
    {
        popCounter++;
        //std::cout<<pointerFunc3->number<<std::endl;
        pointerPop2=pointerPop2->next_number;
    }
    pointerPop=tailPointer;
    while(i<(popCounter-2))
    {
        pointerPop=pointerPop->next_number;
        i++;
    }
    pointerPop->next_number=NULL;
    delete head;
    head=pointerPop;
    //]]
}
}


void stack_class::printStack(){
stack_struct *pointer = head;
if(head == NULL)
{
    std::cout<<"\nNo Members in List.\n";
}
else
{
    std::cout<<"\n\nList Is:\n";
    while(pointer)
    {
        std::cout<<pointer->number<<std::endl;
        pointer=pointer->next_number;
    }
}}
```

Catches that i found:

1. you never declared the tailPointer in the class but using
   frequently.
2. popNumber function does not return anything.
3. Please post the push function also may be the error is in there